# Making database connection in Python with Sybase or odbc

Tags: python, sybase, dbconnection

In my organization we make use of Sybase to create a db service of database and our software connect to this service to make use of database.

I am using python(pycharm) and want to connect to this db service.
Or even if I could create a new service in python code then my work would be done.
Currently I am able to get following connection string information from interactive sql while connecting to the same service-

"UID=;PWD=;Server=;ASTART=No;LINKS=TCPIP()"

I want to be able to create a db connection in python using the above information.
It would be helpful if anyone can give me the sqlalchemy db url(or any working format) for such scenarios.

My simple goal is to be able to connect to the database and get the result of select queries in a list or dictionary.

engine = create_engine('**connectionstring**')

what should be the format of my **connectionstring** given the above information?